# Filtering JSON data and appending to divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, methods, append

I have a local JSON file and I'm trying to filter data from it and append that data to divs in my html file. I'm unable to see the data in the console, so I'm not sure if I'm doing `console.log` incorrectly (see below) or if the data is "inaccessible" based on scope.

#### JS file:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import jsonData from "./test.json";

function _loadDispForm() {
        let dispData = jsonData.d.results.filter(x => {
            return {
                "Title": x.Title,
                "GoalRange": x.GoalRange,
                "Office": x.Office,
                "Role": x.Role,
                "IsFilled": x.IsFilled,
                "Employee": x.Employee,
                "IsActive": x.IsActive,
                "Notes": x.Notes
            }

        })      
        $("#display-form-job-title").append("Title");

        console.log(x.Title);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(dispData));
    }
```

#### JSON snippet:

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
        "Id": 1,
        "Title": "TitleHere",
        "GoalRange": "3",
        "Office": "Somewhere",
        "Role": "FPSL",
        "IsFilled": false,
        "Employee": null,
        "IsActive": true,
        "Notes": null,
        "ID": 1,
        "Attachments": false
...etc
```

#### HTML snippet:

```
<div class="col-6">

  <h3 id="display-form-job-title"></h3>
```

For the most part, the HTML tags for the other key values are similar to this one.

Comment: are you recieving the json

Comment: @Deepak When I `console.log` jsonData outside of the function I can see it.

Comment: please refer my soln

Comment: 1. Your "filter" doesn't look like a filter, it looks like a map. What exactly do you want to happen here? 2. here: `console.log(x.Title);`, x doesn't exist - it only exists inside this function: `jsonData.d.results.filter(x => { //...`.

Comment: @mbojko You're right, I should be using a map and not a filter. In terms of `x` should it be accessible outside of the function in order for it to be used properly?

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have stated, you most likely should be using `.map` ("morph this length N array to a new length N array"), rather than `.filter` ("return length <= N array from length N array, including only elements that satisfies the condition").

```js
a = [1,2,3]
console.log(a.map(a => a + 1)) // [2,3,4]
console.log(a.filter(a => a == 2)) // [2]
console.log(a.filter(a => a > 1)) // [2,3]
```